# How does form.submit timing work?

Tags: javascript

I've come across some javascript code in our codebase that stands out as dangerous to me.

```
function SaveAndClose()
{
  //etc etc some validation
  TheForm.submit();
  window.close();
}
```

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how form submission timing works.  I was hoping someone could enlighten me:
1) When does the form submit happen?
2) How does the close affect the form submission?  Is it possible that there is a race condition here?

I originally expected that the close would not execute (execution would terminate at the submit), but the behavior I am seeing is that both the submit and close are executing (in FF) - the data is being persisted to the DB (via the page of the form's post action), and the window is indeed being closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`submit()` is an asynchronous call.
It kicks off an HTTP request in the background, then continues running the code on the page.

I don't know whether closing the browser window will abort the HTTP request.
However, if this is in a popup window, the form is likely to be submitting to the parent window (using the `target` attribute), so it wouldn't matter.

Comment: it is not using target... without the close the form's post action page is shown.  I am curious how that async call works - is it only starting to execute after all my javascript code is complete?  Do I need to worry about a race condition?

Comment: @csauve: It sends the request immediately (I assume), then continues executing your code during the network call.  I don't know whether this is a safe pattern; I would recommend `target`ing an `<iframe>` in the parent.

Comment: thanks for your help! I will experiment a bit but that definitely sets me in the right direction